# navbar collapse does not collapse bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i'm fairly new to html, and imsimply trying to get the boostrap navbar to collapse but it doesn't work, the button shows up but it does not work, there are so many different questions on this forum concerning this problem but none have worked so far. i know there is a simple thing that i am missing but i can't seem to find where.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-dark" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="bookreviews.html"><i style="font-size: 17px;" class="fa fa-fw fa-book-open"></i> Book Reviews</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"><i style="font-size: 17px" class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact us</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Pricings</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#"><i style="font-size: 17px;" class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Login</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

edit: i have already included these in the head section:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- font awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/52760ad3c3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and this in the bottom of the body section:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

FIXED: by just changing the class of my button to this ( as i was using another bootstrap version):

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You have example properly linked [bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/) navigation, with working `toggler`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Boostrap 5 Navbar with toggler!</title>
</head>

<body>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i tried yours it does work, but mine still doesn't, is it because of the icons i have in the navbar?

Comment: Compare the code and check .. ;-) In my eyes you added the navbar code from a different version of the bootstrap, I think lower version... And you have linked bootstrap 5. That's why this doesn't work. Good Luck and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You need include the scriptjs otherwise the nav collapse will not work
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Here is the link to the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: forgot to mention i have included bootstrap js in the bottom of my body, and bootstrap css in the head. also edited my post.